# Optimize big array search ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a friendship feature.
But I have an issue. When a user is sending a request to a specific user, it is iterating through more than 3k users in order to find the right person.
I'd like to know if there is a ruby method which permits to increase the speed of the search.

I'm using the has_friendship gem

Here is my code :
View friends : index.html.erb

```
<div class="info  d-flex  flex-column">
    <header class="ui basic segment">
      <h3 class="typo text-center mt-2">Ajoutes tes amis </h3>
    </header>
    <div class="ui basic segment">
      <%= form_tag ({controller: 'friends', action: 'search'}) do %>
        <div class="text-center mt-2">
          <input type="align-items-center mt-2" name="search" id="search">
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-light mt-3" type="submit" name="commit" value="Chercher" data-disable-with="Search">
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my controller of friends with the method search :

```
@search = params[:search]
@results = User.find{|x| x.pseudo == @search}
```

Here is my search view : search.html.erb

```
<% if @results.name != current_user.name %>
 <div class="ui vertical clearing segment">
   <span class="ui header">
    <p class="typopo"> Pseudo: <%= @results.pseudo %></p>
    <p class="typopo"> Championnat: <%= @results.player_seasons[0].championship.name %></p>
    <p class="typopo"> Nombre de points: <%= @results.player_seasons[0].number_of_points %></p>
   </span>
  <% if current_user.not_friends.include?(@results) %>
   <div class="ui basic segment">
    <%= form_tag ({controller: 'friends', action: 'create', method: 'post', id: @results.id}) do %>
    <input class="btn btn-light mt-3" type=submit value='Ajouter'>
   <% end %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Here is my schema for the user model and the friendship model :

```
create_table "friendships", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "friendable_type"
    t.integer "friendable_id"
    t.integer "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer "blocker_id"
    t.integer "status"
    t.index ["friendable_id", "friend_id"], name: "index_friendships_on_friendable_id_and_friend_id", unique: true
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "pseudo"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false, null: false
    t.string "blason"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.text "image"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Thank you by advance

Comment: You should use the LIKE query here. User.where("users.pseudo like #{%@search%}")

Comment: I tried this but I have this error, could explain me ? ` PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "brzny" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.pseudo like brzny) ` where brzny is the pseudo the user is submitting

Comment: `User.where("users.pseudo like ?", "%#{@search}%")`, there's a typo in Vishal's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works really fast ! But it doesn't find the user by the pseudo

Comment: I end up with an empty array do you have any ideas ?

Comment: It should `User.where("users.pseudo like ?", "%#{@search}%") ` . Can you please tell me the value of `@search` and the record  you were expecting?

Comment: The value of search is the pseudo the user computed "search"=>"brzny", basically the search value is right, but it doesn't give me the record of the user who has the pseudo "brzny"

Comment: Here are the logs : `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"K1 ...=", "search"=>"Ggf", "commit"=>"Chercher"} User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 128], ["LIMIT", 1]]  Rendering friends/search.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.pseudo like '#%{@search}%') `

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I had a closer look to my logs and found out the problem was in the user controller. I changed the part in relation with .not_friends and now it works. Thnks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're filtering records by their `pseudo` column, in its entirety, you could use `find_by`, which implements the `WHERE` clause plus a `LIMIT` of 1:

```
User.find_by(pseudo: @search)
```

Comment: I already used it, but it's really slowing down everything. It is looking almost through the 3K records

Comment: You mean `find` or `find_by`? 3k rows does not look like a problem for postgres. Perhaps you can add info about your table structure and the result of the query `explain` to dig into the details.

Comment: I tried both, but I think the way it's built is a problem I use the gem has_friendship

Comment: I don't see that could be a problem. What's the SQL you see when you run that query? What does `User.where(id: 1).limit(1).explain` returns?

Comment: I've got this : `  User.where(id: 1).limit(1).explain
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..7.69 rows=1 width=378)
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..7.69 rows=1 width=378)
         Filter: (id = '1'::bigint)
(3 rows) `

Comment: Sorry @gclement, my mistake, you should query the `pseudo` column, not `id`, try once again but this way `User.where(pseudo: <any text value here>).limit(1).explain`.

Comment: It does the same I think : `User.where(pseudo: "Gigi").limit(1).explain
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."pseudo" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["pseudo", "Gigi"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."pseudo" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["pseudo", "Gigi"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..7.69 rows=1 width=378)
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..7.69 rows=1 width=378)
         Filter: ((pseudo)::text = 'Gigi'::text)
(3 rows) `

Comment: So that shows that that query isn't taking long to execute. Maybe there's something else giving you troubles, but if you anyway want, try adding a proper index for the `pseudo` column and see if it changes something.

Comment: What do you mean by a proper index ?

Comment: An index on that column that when you execute a query containing `where column = ...`, then it's used.

Comment: Ok thank you. Also do you have an idea why using @results = User.where("users.pseudo like ?", "#%{@search}%") I do not retrieve the record of the user ?

Comment: @SebastianPalma it's not the only problematic query. There's also the `current_user.not_friends.include?(@results)`. At a glance, this _does_ fetch all non-friends to do a linear search.

Comment: Nice @SergioTulentsev, I just focused in the `User.find ...` part.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are right, I changed this part and everything is working well. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try save `user.pseudo` to db and search by that field. You can improve speed with db index.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? And where should I try this ?